# twisted: multiple logins with a uniq Perspective Broker TCP connection

Tags: twisted

I'm working on a code that use Twisted this way: a client establishes a permanent Perspective Broker TCP connection (ie, the connection is kept open during the whole process live, which can be days, months or years), and performs logins using this broken for different Avatars when needed.

My problem is that the Avatar logout clean up function is [recorded](https://github.com/twisted/twisted/blob/release-18.9.0-9541/src/twisted/spread/pb.py#L1574) by the broker, to be called and removed when the broker TCP connection is [lost](https://github.com/twisted/twisted/blob/release-18.9.0-9541/src/twisted/spread/pb.py#L715).

My problem is that the connection is never lost, and the [broker.disconnects](https://github.com/twisted/twisted/blob/release-18.9.0-9541/src/twisted/spread/pb.py#L541) list increases more and more.

Even worse, the avatar logout function in defined by the code I'm working on has a reference on the Avatar (by closure), and the avatars can be big, causing a problematic memory leak to the whole process.

Here is an example adpated frome the doc:

The server:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Inspired from pb6server.py here:
# https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/pb-cred.html#two-clients

# Copyright (c) Twisted Matrix Laboratories.
# See LICENSE for details.


from zope.interface import implementer

from twisted.spread import pb
from twisted.cred import checkers, portal
from twisted.internet import reactor

PROTOCOL = None


# I didn't find another way to get a reference to the broker: suggestion
# welcome!
class MyFactory(pb.PBServerFactory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        global PROTOCOL
        PROTOCOL = super().buildProtocol(addr)
        return PROTOCOL


class MyPerspective(pb.Avatar):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def perspective_foo(self, arg):
        assert PROTOCOL is not None
        print(f"Leaked avatars: {len(PROTOCOL.disconnects)}")


@implementer(portal.IRealm)
class MyRealm:
    def requestAvatar(self, avatarId, mind, *interfaces):
        if pb.IPerspective not in interfaces:
            raise NotImplementedError
        return pb.IPerspective, MyPerspective(avatarId), lambda: None


p = portal.Portal(MyRealm())
c = checkers.InMemoryUsernamePasswordDatabaseDontUse(
    user0=b"pass0", user1=b"pass1", user2=b"pass2", user3=b"pass3", user4=b"pass4"
)
p.registerChecker(c)
factory = MyFactory(p)

reactor.listenTCP(8800, factory)
reactor.run()
```

And the client:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Inspired from pb6client.py here:
# https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/pb-cred.html#two-clients


from twisted.spread import pb
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.cred import credentials


USERS_COUNT = 5


def main():
    factory = pb.PBClientFactory()
    reactor.connectTCP("localhost", 8800, factory)
    for k in range(10):
        i = k % USERS_COUNT
        def1 = factory.login(
            credentials.UsernamePassword(f"user{i}".encode(), f"pass{i}".encode())
        )
        def1.addCallback(connected)
    reactor.run()


def connected(perspective):
    print("got perspective1 ref:", perspective)
    print("asking it to foo(13)")
    perspective.callRemote("foo", 13)


main()
```

How may I notify the `broker` that the avatar should be cleaned, whitout closing the broker TCP connection?

Thanks!

Comment: PB is complex, complicated, obscure, and barely maintained.  You may want to consider another protocol such as HTTP.

Comment: Thanks, PB will be no more used in the future versions of the product I'm working on, but the past versions are installed at customers and need to be maintained, so I have to deal with it!

Comment: I may just subclass _JellyableAvatarMixin and orverride _cbLogin so it no more do self.broker.notifyOnDisconnect(maybeLogout). Or something like that